# Alternative Application Switcher (Alt+Tab) in a Desktop Environment

Tags: application-switcher

If I understand correctly, each DE has its own Application Switcher (the thing we get by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>). My question is, can the Application Switcher be replaced with a different one?

I mean, for example, in Unity environment, can I get Cinnamon <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, or maybe an entirely new one?

Comment: Each question needs to be a single post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.
first, install compizconfig-settings-manager.
press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal then typing

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

in terminal.
Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and type your root password.
Wait to install then type

```
ccsm
```

in terminal and Click *Application Switcher* in ccsm then *Enable* this.

You can change default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key in Next Window to other key.